# "Sync is currently experiencing problems. It will be back shortly "

Tags: sync, gmail

I just got my S8 yesterday and everything is pretty much smooth sailing except for the fact that I cannot sign in into my school's gmail account. I've searched high and low online, following almost everything I could.

I've noticed that when I try to sign in again online, it says that Chrome has requested a certificate and that you can install certificates from a pkcs#12 file with a .pfx or a .p12 extension. It gives me an option to Install or Cancel but whenever I try to install it gives me a blank document with nothing to install.

Then, when I am on the Google Docs app and signed in with my account, it says to refresh the page because it says "Unable to refresh. Check your network connection then swip down to retry". I swipe down, and a window that says Checking Info.. appears for a brief second and then disappears.

I cleared the cache of the gmail app, rebooted my phone, wiped my phone, reinstalled the app, followed [these](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2650727?hl=en) with no success.

Does anyone have any idea how to log in?

Comment: Have you tried any alternate browser to Chrome?

Comment: Nope. Browser isn't an issue I would think?  I can sign in perfectly fin with my Apple phone. I can try FireFox if you think Chrome is a issue...EDIT: I signed in with my school gmail account for Google Play and it won't connect at all. Signed in with an alternate gmail account and it worked fine...

Comment: Is this "school gmail account" @gmail.com, or on your school's domain?